# Characteristic class invariant under bundle isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $c$ be a characteristic class for principal $G$-bundles and $p_1: E_1 \to X, p_2: E_2 \to X$ be isomorphic principal $G$-bundles, then $c(E_1) = c(E_2)$

Is this part of the defining naturality condition for characteristic class i.e. part of the definition or it can be proved from the definition of characteristic class?

Comment: A characteristic class are a certain natural transformation on the category of $G$-bundles. From a categorical perspective, this means that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are indistinguishable, and thus represent the same element in $H^*(X)$.

Comment: @Kamina: do you mean that by defining the category to be isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles we can identify the characteristic classes of two isomorphic bundles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this depends what definition you give.  It is certainly reasonable to include this in the definition explicitly, and some definitions do (such as [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class#Definition)).  But depending on how you define "pullback", it could follow from the pullback invariance condition.  Specifically, you might formulate pullback invariance as follows: whenever $f:X\to Y$ is a map and $E$ is a bundle on $Y$ and $f^*E$ is *any* pullback of $E$ (i.e., any bundle over $X$ that satisfies the categorical definition of the pullback), then $c(f^*(E))=f^*(c(E))$.  Then if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isomorphic bundles over $X$, an isomorphism $E_1\to E_2$ realizes $E_1$ as a pullback of $E_2$ with respect to the identity map $Id:X\to X$.  Thus pullback invariance would imply $c(E_1)=c(Id^*(E_2))=Id^*(c(E_2))=c(E_2)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Eric!  By "pullback invariance" do you mean the following: an isomorphism $E_1 \to E_2$ realizes $E_1$ as a pullback of $E_2$ with respect to the identity map Id$:X \to X$.  The key to proving $c(E_1) = c(E_2)$ is this identity map.  So I want to make sure that I understand where it comes from.

Comment: I mean that the square whose top map is $E_1\to E_2$, bottom map is $Id:X\to X$, and vertical maps are the projections $E_1\to X$ and $E_2\to X$ is a pullback square.

Comment: Do you mean that any two isomorphic bundles can fit into such a pullback square?  That does not seem to be part of the standard definition of bundle isomorphism. I think that is where I don't quite get it.

Comment: Well, just verify the universal property.  If you have compatible maps $a:F\to E_2$ and $b:F\to X$, just define a map $F\to E_1$ by composing $a$ with the inverse of your isomorphism $E_1\to E_2$, and check that the diagram commutes and this is the only possible choice for such a map $F\to E_1$.

Comment: So Eric, you mean that bundle isomorphism over a common base space must cover the identity map?

Comment: Yes, in this context "isomorphic" means that the isomorphism covers the identity map.  Otherwise, it need not be true that $c(E_1)=c(E_2)$.

Comment: Oh really! In Ralph Cohen's notes he uses Prin$_G(X)$ to denote the set of isomorphism classes of principal $G$-buncles over $X$.  The "isomorphism" in the definition of Prin$_G(X)$ actually is one that covers the identity map on the base space?  On his notes (the topology of fiber bundles) pp.82 he says that by the isomorphism invariance of characteristic classes, a characteristic class $c$ defines a map from Prin$_G(X)$ to $H^*(X)$.

Comment: Yes, "isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over $X$" means with respect to isomorphisms covering the identity (i.e., isomorphisms _over_ $X$).

Comment: Many thanks Eric!  That is my last doubt and it is now time to close this question!